# How to read child of child data from firebase in android / kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read data from my firebase realtime database to a TextView. But every time it shows null in TextView. I want to read single user data. I want to read data when user give input.

My Data Structure look like this..

```
{
  "Date": {
           "04-10-2019": {
                "-LqR-e2UJLJCccqfgGi1":{
                    address: Dhaka
                     date: 04-10-2019
                     name: Mark
                     phoneNo: 017#######   
                     serialNo: -LqR-e2UJLJCccqfgGi1       
                     type: New
                   },
          },

          "05-10-2019": {
                "-LqU-e2UJLJCDcqfgGi9":{
                    address: Dhaka
                     date: 04-10-2019
                     name: Tony
                     phoneNo: 017#######   
                     serialNo: -LqU-e2UJLJCDcqfgGi9      
                     type: OLd
          },

  }
}
```

The code that I am trying.

```
class Info(
           val serialNo: String? = "",
           val name: String = "",
           val address: String = "",
           val phoneNo: String = "",
           val date: String = "",
           var type: String = ""

          )

private fun saveInfo() {
        // Edit Text Field
        val name = editTextName.text.toString().trim()
        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            editTextName.error = "Please Enter Your Name"
            return
        }

        val address = editTextAddress.text.toString().trim()
        if (address.isEmpty()) {
            editTextAddress.error = "Please Enter Your Address"
            return
        }

        val phoneNo = editTextPhoneNo.text.toString().trim()
        if (phoneNo.isEmpty()) {
            editTextPhoneNo.error = "Please Enter Your Phone Number"
            return
        }

        val date = dateText.text.toString().trim()

        //Radio Button
        var type = ""
        when {
            checkboxNew.isChecked -> type += "New"
            checkboxOld.isChecked -> type += "Old"
            radioGroup.checkedRadioButtonId <= 0 -> {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Please Check New or Old", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
                return
            }
        }

        val current = LocalDateTime.now()
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")
        val formatted = current.format(formatter)

        val myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Date").child(formatted)
        myRef.orderByChild(formatted).startAt("28-09-2019").endAt("31-12-2070")

        val patientId = myRef.push().key
        val patient = Info(patientId, name, address, phoneNo, date, type)

        myRef.child((patientId).toString()).setValue(patient).addOnCompleteListener {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Info saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    for (data in dataSnapshot.children) {
                        val user = data.child(formatted).value.toString()
                        dataText.text = user
                    }
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                }
            })

        }
    }
```

I want to show the data into a textview when the user give input and hit a button.

Comment: what is `child(formatted)`?

Comment: child(formatted) creates "dd-mm-yy" formation child as date wise every day -@Peter Haddad

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read the `date` attribute from the database then change this :

```
val user = data.child(formatted).value.toString()
```

Into this:

```
val user = data.child("date").value.toString()
```

Inside the `child()` you need to pass the name of the attribute.

Comment: Actually I need the "04-10-2019" value. when user will input something and hits a button then the given data will be shown into a textview

Comment: this `val user = data.child("date").value.toString()` should give you `04-10-2019`

Comment: yeap but it doesn't retrieving the users given value. Just show 05-10-2019

Comment: Is there any problem with the class?